# Can't increase screen resolution with latest G41 driver

Tags: windows-7, resolution, integrated-graphics, intel-graphics

I have a PC with G41 Express Graphics Chipset and have installed the latest driver. I can't reach the top resolution of "1680x1050". My display is a Samsung SyncMaster E2220.

Comment: What operating system? Version? Any particular configuration?

Comment: Where did you get the latest version of the driver, Windows Update or Intel's website?  Have you installed the relevant chipset drivers as well?

Comment: @vonbrand win7,CPU is pentium E5800

Comment: @cp2141 from Intel's website,what's the relevant?

Comment: @yreenchan if you put in your H/W it should automatically find the drivers.

Comment: @cp2141 yes,but it didn't worked.still remain the bad resolution of 1600x1200

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your monitor has a max resolution of 1920 x 1080.

Intel has a support case about being [unable to use the native resolution](http://www.intel.com/support/graphics/sb/CS-028366.htm)

> On some displays, the native resolution for Intel chipsets is not
>   usable. For example, resolutions for 1920x1080, 1680x1050, and
>   1440x900 are not available in graphics properties.

Try the options Intel provides in that link.

Comment: but I also cannot resolve the problem ,it's just still not available of 1680x1050

Comment: but i still cannot resove the problem,what can i do now?

Comment: Did you follow the steps in the article? Do you have the Samsung drivers installed? Does Windows list the monitor by name/model? Have you contacted Intel? What else have you done?

Comment: Now i can reach the resolution at 1680x1080,but it doesn't appropriate for the screen.I'm so crazy about this strange problem

Comment: I solve the problem now,it's the problem of VGA line.As I change it,the display can perfectly reach the resolution of 1680x1050 without any overflow.Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Glad I could help. You can accept and/or up vote the answer if you feel it helped you.